# How to use data attributes with Font Awesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to convert a `rel` content into a Font Awesome CSS icon, so I won't have to write 20 lines for a simple menu.

Maybe some code would make it easier to understand.

**I tried to do this:**

```
a:before {content: "\(" attr(rel) ")"; font-family: 'FontAwesome';}
```

Basically I am trying to convert the value inside the `rel`  and convert it to a working CSS rule.

**So the link looks like this:**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="f291">Example</a>
```

**The end result should look something like:**

```
a:before {content: "\f291")"; font-family: 'FontAwesome';}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the question may duplicate to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097807/using-attrdata-icon-property-to-display-unicode-before-element). In a simple word - you'll need to use HTML entity, or the unicode character itself, in order to use it in CSS `content` property.

However it's a very interesting idea to use the technique with Font Awesome, so I'm writing this answer, and adding the extra info for it.

I'd suggest to use data attributes [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) instead of [`rel`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), as `rel` is designed for link types.

And on [this page](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) has a complete set of Font Awesome unicode tables. You can either copy/paste the unicode character, or the icon itself. Examples below:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

a::before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: attr(data-fa-icon);
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" data-fa-icon="&#xf206;"> Unicode example</a></p>
<p><a href="#" data-fa-icon=""> Icon example</a></p>
```

Comment: Thats what i did to begin with ;) I am trying to use a wordpress menu and it keeps regecting characters such as "&#x" - but that a wp problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting, I did a quick search, this [tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-icons-wordpress-menus/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There no way to do that in css, because there is no variables. You can use compiled css (like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)). The other way to do that is js. And the third way is to add style inside html in server side.

Comment: i am using less not sass... can you share an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523197/css-values-using-html5-data-attribute y ou van fond more informations here