# Fitting content into a column with icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

When i followed another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MHeqG/) I found that it doesn't work in my case. I use a Font Awesome icon and it somehow interferes with my CSS.

What steps should I take to make the paragraph of text equally indented (in pixels) from the left border and the icon?

The proposed solution that doesn't work in this case:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    width:7px;
}
#right {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="width:200px"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" id="left" style="display:block;vertical-align: top;margin-top:3px"></i><span id="right" style="margin-left: 0px;display:block">A long description adjacent to the input field that doesn't fit into one line and it has to be broken into multiple lines.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34724708/3880255).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive `margin-left` on the containing `div` element, and a negative `margin-left` on the child `img` to move it to the left of the text, like this:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
div .fa {
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
  A long description adjacent to the input field that doesn't fit into one line and it has to be broken into multiple lines.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this and Rory has shown you one. Another method would be to add a `position property` value of `relative` to main(parent element) as shown below, then a `position property` value of `absolute` to .fa. that way you can use `left` with `negative value` to position it as you desire.

**Note:** To have the text wrap around the icon, just float `.fa` to left and then use `margins` to adjust the spaces between the icon and text.

```css
.main {  
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  }


.fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i><span style="margin-left: 0px;display:block;width:100%">A long description adjacent to the input field that doesn't fit into one line and it has to be broken into multiple lines.</span>
</div>
```